# BigQuery GA4 table: add_to_cart plus parameters

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

On GA4 I'am able to create this filter:

- event_name = "add_to_cart"
  AND
- item_category = "Samples Shop"

  AND
- price <= 0

[image: GA4 filter]

Note, the parameter "price" is categorised as "other"

[image: price]

I want to create the same via big query sql.
But I am getting an error at line 9 `param.key = 'price'`

Here my attempt:

```
    SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS user_count
FROM
  `project_id.your_dataset_id.your_table_id`
WHERE
  event_name = 'add_to_cart'
  AND (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'item_category') = 'Samples Shop'
 AND param.key = 'price'
  AND CAST(param.value.int_value AS INT64) <= 0;
```